# Gingerbread has drastically reduced my battery life

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery-life

I have a Nexus One, and since upgrading to 2.3.3, my phone lasts several hours less compared to 2.2.x. I've swapped out to a new battery, which didn't make a difference. In about 14 hours (of nothing more than texting), my phone is at less than 15%. When I check the Battery use under Settings, Android OS is always the top battery consumer.

What can I do about this? Every other update besides this one has been great, but Gingerbread is a total disappointment.

**Update:** This is 100% an issue with wifi. After disabling it, the battery usage of Android OS has dropped from 40% to 2%.  After 16 hours on battery, it's still more than half charged. I'll keep investigating...or revert, because I think Gingerbread just looks fugly.

Comment: FWIW, Gingerbread has also cut my Nexus One battery life (now about 2/3 of what it used to be). Be thankful you even get 14 hours. After my 8 hour day of mostly idle, I go to my phone to discover it has already shutdown.

Comment: That's 14 hours without doing anything ... The keyboard also freezes / crashes a lot. All around terrible update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd have to agree. Are you running the stock update or a 3rd party packaged one? I was having phone reboot issues running a 3rd party ROM. Stock is more stable. But both had poor battery life.

Comment: I installed this right from the phone, it said there was an update available, so I just did it. It wasn't from a 3rd party.

Comment: Same phone, same build, same problem. In fact, my phone sometimes runs hot! Battery consumption shows a huge amount of CPU being consumed by Android OS, sometimes, 3-4 hours out of 12hours.

Comment: Have you reduced the frequency of synchronizations? I reduce most of mine to the lowest possible frequency.

Comment: I haven't reduced the frequency of polling/synchronizations, because I really shouldn't have to. I've read about potential problems with wifi, so I've disabled that and will see if the battery lasts any longer than 14 hours today,

Comment: I haven't had any problem. I'm running ginger yoshi on my HTC Magic with a two year old battery and haven't seen any degradation.

Comment: @wsanville: instead of updating your question to say that this is fixed, please add an answer with that information and "accept" it as the solution.

Comment: I have also heavy battery usage since Gingerbread 2.3.6 is on my Samsung Galaxy S I-9000.
Without using the phone and with low use of internet, the battery runs out in less than 10 hours. That used to be about 2 days!
I switched off a lot of software/applications but that didn't help.
The problem must be in the OS itself. If the problem isn't solved by Google or Samsung, I will have to switch to a non Android smartphone. Dinand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of **2.3.4** this issue is fixed. For other users on previous versions, I temporarily solved this problem by disabling Wifi all together.

Answer (score 5):

Revert?  If the OS itself is not sleeping properly, you can't do much else besides install a kernel or ROM that behaves better.

Comment: I would have to root my phone to do so, correct?

Comment: I don't think so?  Maybe to prevent an OTA update afterwards.  You should be able to just download an update, name it update.zip, put it in the root of your SD card, and reboot.  The 2.2.2 update is linked here for example: http://www.androidcentral.com/nexus-one-android-222-update-pushing-out-build-frg83g

Comment: Alright, and if I want to go back to 2.3.3 (for some strange reason), I just do the same thing with the corresponding zip file?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a Wi-Fi issue, have the stand by settings changed with the new installation?

Settings->Wireless & Networks->Wi-Fi settings

Menu->Advanced->Wi-Fi sleep policy

Has this setting changed from to Never (Which will keep the Wi-Fi on all the time)?

Comment: Thanks for posting how to get to the Wifi sleep policy, I read about that all over the place, but couldn't find it. It's currently set to "Never when plugged in." What I've read suggests there's a bug with the sleep policy, where it malfunctions when trying to sleep and conserve battery, but instead, drains it like crazy. So changing this to "Never" has helped some people. What would you recommend setting it to? I've just disabled wifi entirely, and that helps the battery last longer.

Comment: I'm in a different situation where I pay per MB for mobile data so I set Wi-Fi to never sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the battery statistics? It is said to help with battery life in some cases.

1. Charge the phone completely.
2. While still on the charger, boot into recovery.
3. In recovery, reset the battery statistics.
4. Reboot the phone.
5. When it has booted completely, unplug the charger.
6. Run the phone until the battery is completely flat and the phone turns off.